# Internal Server Error on failed in router

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, toast

In my router, before I goes to the page I launch an rest api request to get data from server in by `beforeEnter` clause like below:

```
beforeEnter: (to, form, next) => {
              getData().then(
                (response) => {
                  //some logic to get data
                  next(); //if no error redirect to page
                },
                (error) => {
                  next(false); //on error not redirect on page - on this moment i want to show info about internal server error
                });
            }
```

and right now i have an question, how to show an toast/notification with "Internal server error" info when I have an error in my `beforeEnter`?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, Ok, I do it

on error:

```
(error) => {
              HelpersService.internalServerErrorToast();
              next(false);
            }
```

in service:

```
  internalServerErrorToast() {
    let bootStrapToaster = new BToast();

    bootStrapToaster.$bvToast.toast("500", {
      title: "Internal Server Error",
      toaster: "b-toaster-bottom-right",
      solid: true,
      variant: "danger",
      appendToast: false,
      noCloseButton: true,
      toastClass: "internalErrorToast",
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using catch. If you are using `then`, you can use `catch`.

```
beforeEnter: function(to, form, next) {
    this.getData().then((response) => {
        next();
    }).catch(error => {
         throw error
    })

}
```

Try this. If not work, comment, We will do something else.